# Is my logic to determine the most sold product correct?

Tags: java, vector

I want to determine the most sold product in a vector of instance Stock.

```
public void mostSold(Vector <Stock> temp){
    System.out.println ("Generating Data... Please Wait!");
    delay(650);
    System.out.println ("-------Most Sold Product(s)-------");
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i ++){
        s = temp.elementAt(i); // Stock s = new Stock();
        sold1 = s.getSold();   
        sold2 = msold.getSold(); //Stock msold = new Stock();
        if(sold1 > sold2)
            msold = s;
        else if (sold2 > sold1)
            msold = msold;
        else if (sold1 == sold2){
            equal = true;
        }
    }
    if(!equal)
        System.out.println (msold.toSold());
    else{
        System.out.println (msold.toSold());
        System.out.println (s.toSold());
    }
    System.out.println ();
}
```

At first when it is executed it works fine, but if I execute it 2 times in a single execution, the console outputs both the mostSold and the leastSold... !

OUTPUT!! 
1st run:    (Works fine)

```
Generating Data... Please Wait!
-------Most Sold Product(s)-------
Product Name: iphone 
Product ID: 0123P
Quantity Sold: 10

Generating Data... Please Wait!
-------Least Sold Product(s)-------
Product Name: nexus 
Product ID: 2345P
Quantity Sold: 1
```

2nd Run:

```
Generating Data... Please Wait!
-------Most Sold Product(s)-------
Product Name: iphone 
Product ID: 0123P
Quantity Sold: 10
Product Name: htc one //WHY IS THIS DISPLAYED!!
Product ID: 3456P
Quantity Sold: 1

Generating Data... Please Wait!
-------Least Sold Product(s)-------
Product Name: nexus 
Product ID: 2345P
Quantity Sold: 1
```

Comment: Can you include the Stock class?

Comment: @ᴘᴀɴᴀʏɪᴏᴛɪs If you wish so yes, but there is alot of code...

Comment: @ᴘᴀɴᴀʏɪᴏᴛɪs Actually I am quite positive that it is from that `mostSold()` method, because the other method which I did not include here, `leastSold()` works perfectly fine, and it was copied and pasted code.

Comment: Why use a `Vector` in 2015?

Comment: @fge This is a school project, and I am bounded to use Vectors.

Comment: Can you please do me a favor and whack your teacher with a sledgehammer?

Comment: @fge Trust me, if I could it would already have been done! haha

Comment: If anyone is intrested... the problem that I was doing was that the boolean variable `equal` was never being reset to `false`. A stupid mistake on my behalf! Thanks all of you for your time and help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have two stocks with equal value.

Assume you have stocks like 1,1,2

So you have default stock with 0 value, comparing with 1 (first stock) in while loop:

```
sold1 > sold2 satisfies and with this default becomes 1st stock with value 1
```

for loop looks for next stock which is again of value 1

```
sold1 == sold2 satisfies and equal becomes true
```

for loop looks for next stock which is again of value 2

```
sold2 > sold1 satisfies msold remains unchanged
```

Now see that equal is true, so you enter else part and print it twice with statement as:

```
 System.out.println (msold.toSold());
 System.out.println (s.toSold());
```

You might just print whatever the max is rather than printing the old value as well.

Comment: `System.out.println (msold.toSold());
 System.out.println (s.toSold());`

What I tried to achieve with this was to print all the products that were the most sold... since they have an equal amount of quantity sold.

Comment: There might be multiple stocks with equal selling count. So when you see two equal sold objects, try to maintain list and add them into it. So when you see multiple equal stocks, you could just print them.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following simple code, which works in two phases:

1. It determines the maximum value for `sold`.
2. It collects all stock items that have this value.
3. It returns all these stock items, instead of printing them.

Here is the code:

```
public List<Stock> getMostSold(Iterable<Stock> stocks) {
  int maxSold = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  for (Stock stock : stocks) {
    maxSold = Math.max(maxSold, stock.getSold());
  }

  List<Stock> result = new ArrayList<>();
  for (Stock stock : stocks) {
    if (stock.getSold() == maxSold) {
      result.add(stock);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

An important thing is that this method has no side-effects, that is, it doesn’t modify any fields of the class or other things. Therefore you can call it as often as you want, and you will always get the same result.

Comment: I see that this is making use of a list.. Is this the same as a vector? Sorry if this is tupid, I am kinda new to java.

Comment: A `List` is not the same as a `Vector`, but they are very similar. The `Vector` is old and rusty, while the `List` is more modern. The main difference is that a `Vector` can be used by multiple threads at the same time (you’ll learn that later). But in most circumstances this is not necessary, and therefore a simple `ArrayList` or `List` is enough.

Comment: To please your teacher, you can replace `List`, `ArrayList` and `Iterable` in the above code with `Vector`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Comparator`:

```
private static final Comparator<Stock> COMPARATOR
    = new Comparator<Stock>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(final Stock o1, final Stock o2)
        {
            return Integer.compare(o1.getSold(), o2.getSold());
        }
    };

// and then (NOTE: assumes at least one element, and no null elements)
public Stock mostSold(final List<Stock> list)
{
    final int size = list.size();
    Stock ret = list.get(0);

    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        if (COMPARATOR.compare(list.get(i), ret) > 0)
            ret = list.get(i);

    return ret;
}
```

If you use Java 8 this is even easier:

```
public Stock mostSold(final List<Stock> list)
{
    return list.stream().max(COMPARATOR).get();
}
```